# P(A|B,C,D) without needing to sample A,B, and C at the same time

Tags: bayesian, inference, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

This is my first question here, so I hope it is posed correctly. It is a Bayesian probability question:
I would like to know the probability of P(A|B,C,D).

I can sample everything (including P(A), P(B), P(C), P(A|B,C), P(B,C|A), P(A|C,D) etc.), except for anything that requires sampling B,C and D all at the same time.
So I cannot compute P(B,C,D), P(B|C,D) P(B,C,D|A) directly (or any such probability).

Is there any way to derive P(A|B,C,D) given these circumstances?

I have looked into using Bayesian Model Averaging to help with this, but I was wondering if there might be a more direct solution with fewer assumptions.

I look forward to your replies and thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: When you say sample, do you mean compute?

Comment: Without any further assumptions this is impossible, for example $B,C,D$ could be mutually exclusive events and then $P(A|B,C,D)$ is not even defined. You have no way of knowing if this is the case from the information you provided

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far!
Yes, by sampling I do mean computing the probabilities.

The example that I am considering concerns inferring values about points that have a spatial relationship. I can compute probabilities that relate information sources in 2D, and I would like to make 3D inferences.

I should have clarified that I assume A,B,C, and D to take discrete values, and all combinations of values are possible (though not equally likely). 
So, B,C, and D are not mutually exclusive (I should have mentioned that from the start - thanks for pointing it out).

Comment: I would also like not to assume B,C, and D to be independent (like some kind of Naive Bayes model). That type of model can give some interesting results, but it is not what I am ideally looking for. Would you have any suggestions on how to approach this?